# What is the expected value and variance of a random variable that is based on another random variable?

Tags: probability, variance, expected-value

Im unsure if this is the correct question, sorry.

Let B be the a random variable with expected value 10 and variance 4 that is defined on B >= 0.

If Y = 4 + B/10, what is the expected value and variance of Y? Y is defined on 0 - 24.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: $\mathbb E(aX+b)=a\mathbb E(X)+b, Var(aX+b)=a^2Var(X)$

Answer (score 0):

Expectation is linear. This means that

$$E[aX + bY] = aE[X] + bE[Y]$$

for random variables $X$ and $Y$ and $a, b \in \mathbb{R}$

We have a similar property for variance, which is true when $X$ and $Y$ are independent.

$$Var[aX + bY] = a^2Var[X] + b^2Var[Y]$$

We also have that $E[a] = a$ and $Var[a] = 0$ (the expectation of a constant is just the constant, and the variance of a constant is zero).

So in your case we have $$E[Y] = E[4 + \frac{1}{10}B] = E[4] + \frac{1}{10}E[B] = 4 + \frac{10}{10} = 5$$

and

$$Var[Y] = Var[4 + \frac{1}{10}B] = Var[4] + \frac{1}{100} Var[B] = 0+ \frac{4}{100} = 0.04$$

Comment: Note that while the result for expectation always holds, for variance it only works if $X$ and $Y$ are "sufficiently" independent. (Being independent is sufficient, but it's not strictly necessary.) For an extreme example, if $X = Y$, then $Var[X+Y] = 4Var[X]$, not $2Var[X]$.

Comment: @Arthur, Yes, you’re right. I’ll add this in.

Comment: @Arthur can you give an example where $X$ and $Y$ are dependent and this property still holds?

Comment: Not off the top of my head, no. But a quick [wikipedia search](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Correlation_and_dependence) led me to an example with $(X, Y)$ being $(1, -1), (0, 0)$ and $(1,1)$ each with probability $\frac13$. In this case $X$ and $Y$ are uncorrelated, and the variance of their sums is indeed the sum of their variances.

Comment: But you said that independence is sufficient but not necessary for the property to hold. So I assume there are cases where $X$ and $Y$ are *not* independent and yet $Var[X + Y] = Var[X] + Var[Y]$. Or am I missing something?

Comment: Uncorrelated does not mean independent. $X$ and $Y$ in my example are very dependent (if you know the value of $Y$, you know the value of $X$, for instance).

Comment: Ahh, I see! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

We can use the linearity of expectation to find $E(Y) = E(4+ B/10) = E(4) + E(B/10) = 4 + \frac{1}{10}E(B) = 4 + 10/10 = 5.$

Similarly for the variance, we have $Var(Y) = Var(4 + B/10) = \frac{1}{100}Var(B) = 4/100 = 1/25.$